# How to prevent discoloration or parts in storage?

Tags: storage

I recently moved into a 1 bedroom apartment, and I am storing my Lego sets out in the living area. There is one problem: one wall is practically all window. Since it is unrealistic to have the blinds closed all of the time (since the lighting isn't great), and I don't have the space or money to buy display cabinets with the special glass that filters UV light, I installed [UV film](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gila-36-in-x-180-in-3-in-1-Heat-Control-Window-Film-50167279/205866640) to the windows.

Will this be enough to save my Lego sets from suffering from discoloration, or should I be doing something else? This situation is only for a year or two, then I hope to buy a house where my sets can safely live in the basement, away from sunlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Product description says:

> UV protection helps reduce fading on flooring, furniture, portraits, blinds and draperies

Reduce, not eliminate, because such film cannot remove 100% of UV, and regular light can also participate in fading a bit.

If you want to store them, not to display them, then box will do. One that isn't transparent. There are opinions that airtight boxes help, too, but I haven't tested that. Regular dark box did a pretty ok (not perfect) job for me when I stored my bricks for many years.

Comment: I want to have them on display, has anyone (Lego or someone independent of Lego) measured how long it takes before white starts to turn yellow/tan?  I have never had my bricks turn this color, but I have inherited some sets with white bricks that are so discolored they almost match the light tan bricks.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam measurement is impossible - exact recipe for LEGO plastic was changed a few times, so any long term results had to be outdated. Modern recipe is supposed to be rather resistant to color changes. Also, it depends where on Earth you are, on what side are your windows, is ozone layer good where you live and so on.